# Proving $2c(1-c)+(1-2c)(a-c)b>0$ assuming $a\in(0,1), b\in(0,1), c\in(0,1)$

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I have the following inequality I am trying to prove using the assumptions $a\in(0,1), b\in(0,1), c\in(0,1)$:

$2c(1-c)+(1-2c)(a-c)b>0$

The following Mathematica code (also visible in this [online notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/59255140-0924-41a6-8819-190d3bb12dd5)) shows the inequality to be true:

```
Simplify[2c(1-c)+(1-2c)(a-c)b>0,0<a<1&&0<b<1&&0<c<1]
```

Any pointers (math or software) in the right direction would be much appreciated. I have tried using Trace in Mathematica, to no avail. As for math, I have tried expanding but cannot eliminate terms in such a way as to get anything tractable, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$2c(1-c)+(1-2c)(a-c)b = 2c(1-c)(1-b)+ba(1-c)+bc(1-a) > 0.$$

> $2c(1-c)+(1-2c)(a-c)b = 2c(1-c)+(1-2c)ab - (1-2c)cb$
>  $= 2c(1-c)+(1-2c)ab - (2-2c)cb + cb$
>  $= 2c(1-c)(1-b)+(1-2c)ab + cb$
>  $= 2c(1-c)(1-b) + (ab - abc) + (cb - abc)$

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the type of demonstration I was looking for (on my end, I figured an inelegant way of doing it by splitting the 3 cases for c<1/2, c=1/2 and c>1/2, but your proof is the one I wish I had found).

Comment: @sg1234 There are some other proofs e.g. noting that the expression is linear in $b$ (thus we only need to prove the case that $b = 0$, or$b = 1$).

Answer (score 3):

Let:
$f(c) = 2(b-1)c^2+(2-(2a+1)b)c+ab$
$b\in(0,1) \Rightarrow$ $f(c)$ is up-convex function
$f(0)=ab > 0$
$f(1)=(1-a)b > 0$
Hence  $f(c) > 0$ for all $c \in (0,1)$

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the other answer (by Rver Li) simply because it is more in line with the kind of algebraic proof I was aiming for, but I appreciate your answer and am upvoting it as well.